# ApostropheJS get index of loop

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am creating a blog on apostrophe JS and I want the first blog post in the index to have a longer preview than the rest of the blogs in the index. Is there a way to get the index of the loop? Or a different way to do this?

```
{%- for piece in pieces -%}
  {{ renderBlogListing(piece) }}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Apostrophe uses Nunjucks, which is a JavaScript port of Jinja, which is also well known in its PHP port, Twig.

All of these let you access the loop index in two ways:

`loop.index`: the current iteration of the loop (counting from 1)

`loop.index0`: the current iteration of the loop (counting from 0)

See the [nunjucks documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) for quite a bit more.